# JUnit5 integration tests with Gradle 4.6

Tags: gradle, junit5

Gradle 4.6 added [support](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#junit-5-support) for JUnit5.

This works for me as long as I don't have another sourceset for e.g. integration tests: I do not know how to enable `useJUnitPlatform()` in my integration tests.

What I was able to do is to have `test` task working with new JUnit5 support, but my `testInt` task was using JUnit5 console and running tests as it would run from command line. At the end I ditch JUnit5 support in gradle and rollback to using JUnit5 console for both tests.

How to enable Gradle 4.6 JUnit5 support on other tasks then `test`?

Answer (score 11):

If your integration test task is also a `Test` task, you may configure all test tasks via:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Or configure it explicitly:

```
task testInt(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    ...
}
```