# JUnit5 not generating test-result TEST-*.xml that JUnit4 used to

Tags: android, junit4, junit5, junit-jupiter

When I used JUnit4 in my projects it seemed that each time a test ran, it would generate a `TEST-*.xml` report in app/build/test-result. Jenkins would use these XML reports to display failing and passing tests on each build.

I've replaced JUnit4 with JUnit5 with the following in build.gradle:

```
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2"
```

When running tests with JUnit 5, I'm no longer seeing these TEST-*.xml files being generated. As soon as I drop back to JUnit4, they are.

Is this no longer available in JUnit5 or is there something I have to set on each test in order to get these XML reports?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. In order for the XML reports to be generated for each test you need to include the following in your build.gradle:

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.2'
```

As well as:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This other post may also be of use to others: [JUnit5 integration tests with Gradle 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365010/junit5-integration-tests-with-gradle-4-6)

Comment: I also hat to add `reports { junitXml.setEnabled(true) }` inside the task block.